# Interval Timer for Windows

Tags: windows, timer

Any App Similar to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybrid.intervaltimer
For Windows

Answer (score 1):

This question would benefit from a bit more detail about what windows version and what the app does (or do you expect us to download it, run it and work out all its functions before we think of a recommendation?) but assuming it times the amount of time before something like the washing or cooking finishes, windows 8 and 10 have a timer built in:

[image]
Image courtesy of howtogeek.com

Just click start and search for Alarm